# Running .net application over a network

Tags: windows, security, active-directory, .net, clickonce

I need some advice please. I need to enable a .Net application to run over a network share, the problem is that this will be on clients network shares and so the path will not be identical.

I've had a quick look at ClickOnce and the publish options in VS2008 but it wants a specific network share location - and I'm assuming this location gets stored somewhere when it does its thing.

At the moment the job is being done with a old VB6 application and so gets around all these security issues, but that application is poorly written and almost impossible to maintain so it really needs to go.

Is it possible for the domain controller to be set up to allow this specific .Net application to execute? Any other options would be welcomed as I want to get this little application is very business critical.

I aught to say that the client networks are schools, and thus are often quite locked down as are the client machines, so manually adding exceptions to each client machine is a big no no.

Marlon

Answer (score 1):

With .net 3.5 SP1 running applications over the network has the same security as running them locally, so you should be able to run it the same way that you currently run your vb6 application.

Alternatively, the easiest way to do this with ClickOnce is to host the application on an http server somewhere (whether inside the school network or outside of it).

Comment: unfortunately we're restricted to .NET 2.0 for the moment.